# IP Forwarding on windows OS machine

Tags: windows, network-programming

is it possible to configure windows machine to do IP Forwarding .
if yes could someone explain how or point to some material on the internet which explain how to do this .

also if there are some WIN32 API which help with this ?

Answer (score 0):

For windows XP:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315236

Answer (score 0):

You have not really mentioned a language you would like to use, so I'm just going to point you to a generic way to set up IP Forwarding (which involves editing the registry) right [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315236). You can easily edit the registry in C# (I'll assume you're using it), you can see it right [here](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-snippet-tutorial-editing-the-windows-registry).

And, for C++/C: you can see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724895.aspx), [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724837.aspx) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724911.aspx).